# Is this possible ( - ) + + - - - = 100 I can do many other way

Tags: mathematics

Insert the numbers 1-9 inclusive each only once into the calculation to arrive at the answer 100.

> ( - ) + + - - - = 100

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's

> possible: $(68 - 2) + 51 + 3 - 4 - 7 - 9 = 100$

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative answer. The parentheses in the question would be redundant if you only did addition and subtraction (and concatenation). To actually make them useful, I used an implied multiplication:

> $$(23-1)5+4+8-6-7-9 \\= 110+4+8-6-7-9 = 100$$

Edit:
If you use two implied multiplications, you don't need concatenation at all:

> $$4(9-5)7+1+3-2-6-8\\ = 112+1+3-2-6-8 = 100$$